# default value in combobox as value from store

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I'm trying to get a return value of my json store to setValue in my combobox. The value of this json value is the current selected option in the database. My this.selectedCat store returns the current category value of the record where it's working in. my this.store returns all the available select options.

```
  var fields = {
  fields: ['text'] 
};
var notfields ={
  fields:['category']
}
this.store = new GO.data.JsonStore({
  url: GO.settings.modules.infoscherm.url + 'json.php',
  baseParams:{
    task:'selects'
  },
  root: 'results',
  fields: fields.fields
});

  this.selectedCat = new GO.data.JsonStore({
  url: GO.settings.modules.infoscherm.url + 'json.php',
  baseParams: {
    task:'currentselectedcat',
    id:'id'
  },
  root: 'results',
  fields: notfields.fields
});


  this.category = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
  name: 'category', 
  width: 100,
  store: this.store, 
  fieldLabel: "Categorie", 
  displayField:'text', 
  triggerAction: 'all', 
  editable: false, 
  selectOnFocus:true, 
  value: this.selectedCat //returns [object Object] naturally
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start listening the "load" event of "Ext.data.JsonStore".
And the attached handler of "load" event will contain code to select any particular value by using "setValue" function of combobox object...

P.S. : Store values are made available in combobox drop down menu only if you configured the "store" config of combobox to the store object, in your case, you need to implement some logic within the handler of "load" event.